# Confusing JSON Object and JSON Array in Android

Tags: android, json

URL JSON Parsing Error. Please check my code.

```
{
    "info": "Central Bank of Myanmar",
    "description": "Official Website of Central Bank of Myanmar",
    "timestamp": "1448611200",
    "rates": 
{

    "USD": "1,300.0",
    "CZK": "51.055",
    "JPY": "1,060.2",
    }

}
```

Activity code is:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.json_object);

    TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    String data = "";
    try {
        String ka =callURL("http://forex.cbm.gov.mm/api/latest");

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(ka);
        JSONObject servicedata = object.getJSONObject("rates");
        String USD = servicedata.getString("USD");

        data += "USD Currency " + USD +" ";
        output.setText(data);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Call URL give me error.

```
public static String callURL(String myURL) {
    System.out.println("Requeted URL:" + myURL);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    URLConnection urlConn = null;
    InputStreamReader in = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(myURL);
        urlConn = url.openConnection();
        if (urlConn != null)
            urlConn.setReadTimeout(60 * 1000);
        if (urlConn != null && urlConn.getInputStream() != null) {
            in = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream(),
                    Charset.defaultCharset());
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(in);
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                int cp;
                while ((cp = bufferedReader.read()) != -1) {
                    sb.append((char) cp);
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception while calling URL:"+ myURL, e);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Please, show your logcat.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what error you're receiving, and where.

Comment: And your json is not valid!

Comment: Maybe it is  `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`?

Answer (score 1):

Try with android **volly library**  It is developed by Google.
You can easily convert json to java and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

I put this code under the setContentView and code it work. Thank your advertises.
I spent the time about one day for this.